# How do I work with JSON-like data along with vector search in Astra DB

Tags: javascript, json, mongoose, vector, cassandra

I've an Astra DB cluster and I'd like to work with JSON-like structures along with vector search on them via my Mongoose library in my javascript app. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

There is a [JSON API](https://www.datastax.com/blog/introducing-the-new-json-api-for-astra-db?utm_medium=social_organic&utm_source=Madhavan_Sridharan&utm_campaign=json-api&utm_content=blog) that we could leverage for this purpose and have vector search data combined with it. The complete documentation is available right [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/develop/dev-with-json.html).

An example to insert regular data + vector embedding would be:

```
curl -s --location \
--request POST https://${ASTRA_DB_ID}-${ASTRA_DB_REGION}.apps.astra.datastax.com/api/json/v1/purchase_database/vector_collection \
--header "X-Cassandra-Token: $ASTRA_DB_APPLICATION_TOKEN" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "Accept: application/json" \
--data '{
    "insertOne": {
        "document": {
            "_id": "4",
            "name": "Coded Cleats Copy",
            "description": "ChatGPT integrated sneakers that talk to you",
            "$vector": [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]
        }
    }
}'
```

and fetching using vector embedding using ANN can be done as follows:

```
curl -s --location \
--request POST https://${ASTRA_DB_ID}-${ASTRA_DB_REGION}.apps.astra.datastax.com/api/json/v1/purchase_database/vector_collection \
--header "X-Cassandra-Token: $ASTRA_DB_APPLICATION_TOKEN" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "Accept: application/json" \
--data '{
  "find": {
    "sort" : {"$vector" : [0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.35, 0.55]},
    "options" : {
        "limit" : 100
    }
  }
}'
```

p/s: Disclaimer, I work with DataStax as of this writing.